# How to create a safe generic array object in java?

Tags: java, arrays, generics

Hey this is my first post and i have this problem 
as you can see this the required method [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2DD4.png)

so i tried to create an array but an exception is showed 
so is there any suggestions ?

this my code

```
public class GArrayFactory {

// Create and return an array of size n

public static <T extends Comparable<T>> GArray<T>[] getGArray(int n) {

    GArray<T>[] array = (GArray<T>[]) new Object[n];

    return array ;
```

and this the **exception**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [LGArray;
at GArrayFactory.getGArray(GArrayFactory.java:9)
```

Comment: Looks like you've made a typo in your code. Notice `LGarray` instead of `GArray`.

Comment: @Gendarme No, that is just how reference descriptors are composed, i.e. `"L" + <binary class name> + ";"`.

Comment: the screenshot you attached has `GArray<T>` return type, but not `GArray<T>[]` as in the code. Which one is required ?

Comment: This is also a good duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/how-to-create-a-generic-array-in-java

Comment: @Gendarme The component type of the array they're trying to create isn't a type coming from a type parameter..

Answer (score -1):

You can create generic arrays using this method:

```
public class GArrayFactory<E> {

    private E[] array;

    public GArrayFactory(Class<E> clazz, int size) {
        final E[] array = (E[]) Array.newInstance(clazz, size);
        this.array = array;
    }

    public E[] getArray() {
        return array;
    }
}
```

Further explanation can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/how-to-create-a-generic-array-in-java)